# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me. The errors are in the left but i don't  I don't know what to do anymore.

The objective is to get the words between Source: and Description:

I have this error: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

```
SELECT Instance.instance_id   
    ,DBSysJobHistory.job_id
    ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id    
    ,SUBSTRING(DBSysJobHistory.message, 19, 25) Executedby      
    ,LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message), CHARINDEX(':ecruoS', REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message)) - 2))+'Description:', CHARINDEX('Description:',REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message), CHARINDEX(':ecruoS', REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message)) - 2))+'Description:')-1) AS Sources
    ,LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message), CHARINDEX(' :noitpircseD', REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message)) - 2))+ 'End Error', CHARINDEX(' End Error',REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message), CHARINDEX(':noitpircseD', REVERSE(DBSysJobHistory.message)) - 2))+'End Error')-1) AS Descriptions
    ,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(DBSysJobHistory.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') run_durations
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
JOIN (SELECT DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ,MAX(DBSysJobHistory.instance_id) as instance_id
        FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory DBSysJobHistory
        GROUP BY DBSysJobHistory.job_id
        ,DBSysJobHistory.step_id
        ) AS Instance ON DBSysJobHistory.instance_id = Instance.instance_id
    WHERE DBSysJobHistory.run_status <> 1
```

Comment: It seems like you have an Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function... I suggest you remove code step by step until the error disappears.

Comment: @jarlh How do I do that?

Comment: If `CHARINDEX` doesn't find the characters you are expecting you're going to end up with a negative number, and you can't have the `LEFT` -2 characters.

Comment: Start with putting `--` first in one of the rows starting with `,LEFT(REVERSE`. Is the error still there after the edit?

Comment: it seems the string length given to the function surpassed the actual length. Try executing the substring or left function separately to find the issue Hope this helps

Comment: I've already commented on the LEFT and the problem is in the LEFT, I'll try to do step by step

Comment: I've done this: `replace(SUBSTRING(DBSysJobHistory.message, CHARINDEX('Source:', DBSysJobHistory.message +'Source: ' )  + LEN('Source: ') - 7, CHARINDEX('Description:',DBSysJobHistory.message) - (CHARINDEX('Source: ', DBSysJobHistory.message))), 'Source: ', '')`